# problem with Stream provider with firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, provider

i have two providers, and i have used MultiProvider, the ChangeNotifierProvider is working, but the problem with StreamProvider, this is my example:

main.dart

```
class Makani extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Db db = Db();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(create: (context)=> db.getLocations(),),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Model(),),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Map(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

db.dart

```
class Db {
  FirebaseFirestore  locationList =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Locations>> getLocations() {

    return locationList.collection('locations').snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Locations.fromFireStore(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }
}
```

location.dart

```
class Locations{
   String title;
   String body;

  Locations({this.title, this.body});

    Locations.fromFireStore(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : title = data['title'],
        body = data['body'];


}
```

tile.dart

here (loc) return null!!! and i don't know why ?

```
class tiles extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var loc = Provider.of<List<Locations>>(context);

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
        height: 140.0,
        child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              reverse: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: loc.length,
              itemScrollController: tilesController,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                addMarker(loc[index]);
                return tile(loc[index]);
              },
```

and i call this class inside Map() which i called it inside main()

Comment: use yield instead of return. yield doesn't end the whole function unlike return. Also, why not use FutureBuilder instead?

Comment: yield doesn't work, but  i need to use StreamProvider not anything else, i saw a tuturial like this exactly it is here"
https://medium.com/@babinsamrat123/fetch-cloud-firestore-data-stream-in-your-flutter-app-using-streamprovider-add-data-to-cloud-fa9971a5985c

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you'd be better off using pagination: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2

Comment: do you have any tutorial about that

Comment: the link I gave you is a tutorial already. You can google the rest of the things you need if the link isn't enough.